# Can't run ssh through tor network

Tags: ssh, tor

I can ssh to a machine running openssh. I want to add anonymity which is why I am interested in Tor. I came accross [this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Misc#SSH) and I'm trying SSH: Method 3 (socat).

This is what my sshd_config file looks like:

```
Host MyHost-tor
ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4A:localhost:192.168.*.*:22,socksport=9050
```

The instructions seem pretty straightforward and it says "Now you can simply use ssh MyHost-tor."

I run ssh MyHost-tor and I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhost-tor: Name or service not known
```

Am I completely off or missing something?

Comment: > This is what my sshd_config file looks like: Please use `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or (better) `~/.ssh/config` Not `sshd_config`!

Comment: tried changing the ssh_config and still same "ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhost-tor: Name or service not known"

Answer (score 0):

```
Host MyHost-tor
...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhost-tor: Name or service not known
```

Config file "Host" values are case-sensitive. When you run ssh, you have to give the hostname the same way it appears in the config file.

Comment: I did enter the name the way it appears but the output returns in in small caps.